# Non-capturing group gets displayed in C#

Tags: c#, regex

For the below line

```
DCS120170517220207-FIC-023.FLW  07-FIC-023    00060Y000000011.266525G
```

I am trying to get just the date. But the non capturing group seems to be ignored. Below is the result. How do I just get the date?

```
DCS1
DCS120170517 //This should be just 20170517
220207-FIC-023.FLW
07-FIC-023
Y
G
```

...

```
public static void parsePlainFile(string line)
{
    string patDcsName   = @"DCS[1-5]|DCSG";
    string patDate      = @"(?:^.{4})([2-9][0-9]{3}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])";
    string patTagName   = @"[0-9]{6}-[A-Z]{2,4}-[0-Z]{2,4}\.[0-Z]{3}";
    string patRodsName  = @"(?<=\s)[0-9]{2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-[0-9]{3}(?=\s)";
    string patFreq      = @"(?<=\d{5})(Y|N)(?=\d{9})";
    string patUnit      = @"\w$";

    Match m = Regex.Match(line, patDcsName);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
     m = Regex.Match(line, patDate);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
     m = Regex.Match(line, patTagName);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
     m = Regex.Match(line, patRodsName);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
     m = Regex.Match(line, patFreq);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
     m = Regex.Match(line, patUnit);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);

}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] - remove all the parts that don't matter, reduce the input to just enough to show the problem, and ideally put the whole thing in the form of something we can copy, paste, compile and run.

Comment: You're looking for a negative lookahead, try this instead `(?!^.{4})([2-9][0-9]{3}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is ignoring the capturing groups.

```
string line = @"DCS120170517220207-FIC-023.FLW  07-FIC-023    00060Y000000011.266525G";
string patDate = @"(?:^.{4})([2-9][0-9]{3}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])";

Match m = Regex.Match(line, patDate);

foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{g.Index}: {g.Value}");
}
```

`m.Value` is group zero -- the entire match, irrespective of groupings. Since you wisely marked the first group as non-capturing, group 1 is the date.

I suggest naming your capturing groups, for ease of maintenance:

```
string line = @"DCS120170517220207-FIC-023.FLW  07-FIC-023    00060Y000000011.266525G";
string patDate = @"(?:^.{4})(?<date>[2-9][0-9]{3}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])";

Match m = Regex.Match(line, patDate);

var date = m.Groups["date"].Value;
```

### Update

Wiktor Stribiżew observes that the non-capturing group is otiose. The following pattern will behave identically to your original pattern. The first capturing group is still `m.Groups[1]`, however, because `m.Groups[0]` is always the entire match, irrespective of groups.

```
string patDate = @"^.{4}(?<date>[2-9][0-9]{3}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])";
```

Comment: Thank you. It had worked fine on RegExr so wasn't sure what was wrong

Comment: Is there something similar to RegExr but uses C# Regex engine?

Comment: @null You can try regex101, it shows that the full string is still capture group 0 and that the string you want is group 1 so you can catch this in future

Comment: `(?:^.{4})` = `^.{4}`

Comment: @null [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net) does .NET regexes, regex101 is for PCRE and JS.